# Generic method for validation of paperclip files in different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-validators

I have 2 models users , companies

User model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
             ...
                :whiny=>false
validates_with ImageSizeValidator
validates_with ImageTypeValidator
validates_with ImageConvertionValidator
```

Company model:

```
has_attached_file :logo,
#the rest is similar
```

I have done validation for users and put it in validation_helper

```
class ImageSizeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
 def validate(record)
   if record.avatar_file_name.present?
     record.errors[:base] << (I18n.t :in_between, scope:  "activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.avatar_file_size") unless record.avatar_file_size.to_i < 200000
   end
 end
end
class ImageTypeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
 def validate(record)
  if record.avatar_file_name.present?
    record.errors[:base] << (I18n.t :file_type, scope: "activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes") unless ['image/jpeg', 'image/gif','image/png'].include?(record.avatar_content_type)
  end
 end
end
```

My problem is that the names will be different so avatar_file_name for users and logo for companies.

Do I have to do a specific method for each?
How can I work this around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add options. If you take a look at [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_with), you can pass arguments in block:

```
#model
validates_with ImageSizeValidator, paperclip_field_name: :avatar

#validator
 def validate(record)
   if record.send(options[:paperclip_field_name].to_s+"_file_name").present?
     record.errors[:base] << (I18n.t :in_between, scope:  "activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.#{options[:paperclip_field_name]}_file_size") unless record.send(options[:paperclip_field_name].to_s+"_file_name").to_i < 200000
   end
 end
```

but much easier to use `validate_each` method

```
#model
validates :avatar, image_size: true, image_type: true, image_conversion: true

#validator
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  if record.send(attribute.to_s+"_file_name").present?
    record.errors[:base] << (I18n.t :in_between, scope:  "activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.#{attribute}_file_name)") unless record.send(attribute.to_s+"_file_name").to_i < 200000
  end
end
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted, i'm a ror noob and sometimes i just can't figure out stuff, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip has built-in support for validations (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations). If their validation are not a fit for your problem you can look on how they are doing it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master/lib/paperclip/validators

Comment: well paperclip sometimes send awfull error messages with no validators (ex: corrupt files, names with chars like éáã)
so i guessed i would do all myself.
but i should try and read how were they doing and i migth had an idea of the option func Ivan mention